# Formula for Force between two Solenoids

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, magnetic-fields

Given two identical solenoids (with appropriate core) $S_0$ and $S_1$ with length=$L$, radius=$R$, number of turns per unit length=$n$. Let these two solenoids be held with the two poles facing each other at distance $x$ (in a hollow glass tube, so they can travel in only in x axis). How do we approximate the force of repulsion at distance $x$, if $k$ Amps of current is passed through two solenoids in opposite direction?

The closest I came across is this wiki article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_between_magnets) which states:

> For two cylindrical magnets with radius $R$, and length $L$, with their magnetic dipole aligned, the force can be computed analytically using elliptic integrals. In the limit $x << R$, the force can be approximated by:
> $$F(x)=\frac{\pi\mu_0M^2R^4} 2 [\frac1 {x^2}+\frac1{(x+2L)^2}-\frac2 {(x+L)^2}]$$
> where $M$ is the magnetization of the magnets. For small values of $x$, the results are erroneous as the force becomes large for close-to-zero distance.

I have few queries regarding this formula:

1. It states "*In the limit $x << R$*". If $x=CR$, for what minimum value (and beyond) of $C$ the formula is a good approximation? This isn't mentioned anywhere?
2. Since this is for permanent magnets what is the corresponding formula for similar electromagnet setup that is a good approximation (including the distance limits)?

P.S. My background is not physics, and I am looking for a good enough black box approximation (similar to above). Alternatively, a program where I can input the parameters and which can compute the approximate force.

Since, my setup needs to use repulsion, ideally, my primary priority is to calculate it when the magnets are close together since for small $x$ the force would be maximum (from $x=0$ to as wide range of distances as possible), for a practical/physical setup. It would be helpful if there is a good way to know the approximate force I can expect for any such setup and any distance $x$.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of magnetic behavior, a bar magnet tens to act like it has an electric current flowing around its perimeter. For purposes of analysis it is often convenient to replace the bar by a solenoid if similar size, shape, and dipole moment: m = MV = NIA. Then the dipole moment per volume: M = NIA/AL = nI, where, n, is the turns per unit length, and, I, is the current in the equivalent solenoid. It can be shown, by  an integral summation of the contributions from each segment of current carrying wire, that the magnetic field at any point on the axis of a solenoid is given by the formula: B = (1/2)$μ_o$nI[sin($θ_2$) - sin($θ_1$)] where the, θ's, are measured at the position of, B, from the perpendicular to the axis, to the perimeter of the far and near ends of the solenoid. (If the solenoid has a magnetic core, the contributions from the solenoid and core add.)  Placing a second solenoid on the axis of the first' and assuming that the field off axis is about the same as on the axis, permits calculation of the force on each turn of the second solenoid. (It can be shown that this leads to the formula in terms of “pole strengths” sighted by your reference.)  As they point out, the assumption about the field off axis is only somewhat reasonable if the separation is large relative to the radius. I would think a factor of five might give a reasonable approximation. For forces at smaller distances (for a given pair of solenoids) you might calculate some forces at larger distances and the force using their formula for two adjacent set of pole areas. Plot these on a graph, and fit a smooth curve to the gap.  Better yet, build the device and measure the forces.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understood some of it. To reconfirm: 

Case 1: for Cr=x (C>=5) the above approximation is ok. For solenoids, we simply have M=nI in the above formula the new formula being:

$F(x)=\frac{\pi\mu_0(nI)^2R^4} 2 [\frac1 {x^2}+\frac1{(x+2L)^2}-\frac2 {(x+L)^2}]$

Case 2: For smaller gaps (Cr=x, say C=1/10) we can use the other formula [Force between two nearby magnetized surfaces of area A]:

$F=\frac{\mu_0{H}^2A} 2 = \frac{{B}^2A} 2\mu_0$


1. How do we find B or H for a given current value?

Comment: 2. I am a bit unclear about this part though: "(If the solenoid has a magnetic core, the contributions from the solenoid and core add.)" Lets say instead of an air core (the default case we assumed above) I have a different core: lets say [Iron (99.95% pure Fe 
annealed in H) = Relative permeability, max., μ/μ0 = 200,000] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permeability_(electromagnetism) how do I adjust the formula. I am a bit unclear with that. I am guessing we need to multiply each of the above formula with (200,000)?

Comment: 3. Surely the force cannot keep increasing arbitrarily with increase in current value. We will reach some threshold level beyond which the increase in current would not increase the force much (I think its related to saturation). How do we calculate this current 
value beyond which the force doesn't increase much (given other parameters such as r, x etc.) in both these cases?

Comment: At the end of a (long) solenoid (with no core) the, B, is approximately (1/2)$μ_o$nI. With an iron core, only the contribution from the core would be multiplied by 2E5.  Once you saturate the core, the only increase of the field would be due to the (much weaker) contribution from the solenoid.

Comment: Thanks again. Please bear with me (due apologies beforehand): For query 1. (I am assuming L=5R or more for a 'long solenoid' with no core), the force would be:  $F(x)=\frac{(nI)^2A{{\mu}_0}^3} 8$.

Query 2: I am still confused. I am assuming $F_{Total}(x)=F_{Solenoid}(x)+F_{Core}(x)$. And above we have calculated just $F_{Solenoid}(x)$ and as there is no core $F_{Total}(x)=F_{Solenoid}(x)$. But, if there is a core I didn't see a formula for it? If possible can you explicitly state it?

Comment: Query 3: Similarly, if we have a core, how do we explicitly calculate the amount of current required for achieving saturation at distance x (say beyond x=5R) given all the other parameters? Can you please point to the formula?